# Rails 4 CollectionProxy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have  a collection on a form for a model named bill that is displaying the collection with a text box with 
`#<Sponsorship::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f99a874bcd0>`
instead of the dropdown. Any ideas?

## bill.rb

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :congress_person
        has_many :bps, :dependent => :destroy
        has_many :committees, :dependent => :destroy
        has_many :sponsorships, -> { where(kind: :primary) }, class_name: "Sponsorship" 
        has_many :cosponsorships, -> { where(kind: :secondary) }, class_name: "Sponsorship"

        has_many :sponsors, class_name: 'CongressPerson', through: :sponsorships
        has_many :cosponsors, class_name: 'CongressPerson', through: :cosponsorships
```

## congress_people.rb

```
has_many :sponsorships, -> { where(kind: :primary) }, class_name: "Sponsorship", foreign_key: :sponsor_id
    has_many :cosponsorships, -> { where(kind: :secondary) }, class_name: "Sponsorship", foreign_key: :sponsor_id

    has_many :sponsored_bills, through: :sponsorships, source: :bill
    has_many :cosponsored_bills, through: :cosponsorships, source: :bill
```

## sponsorship.rb

```
belongs_to :bill
belongs_to :sponsor, class_name: "CongressPerson"
belongs_to :cosponsor, class_name: "CongressPerson"
```

## _form.html.haml

```
...
.row-fluid
                .col-md-12
                    %h3 Sponsor
                    #sponsors-form
                        = f.simple_fields_for :sponsors do |sponsor|
                            = render 'sponsor_fields', f: sponsor
                        .links
                        = link_to_add_association 'Add Sponsor', f, :sponsors, class: 'btn btn-secondary add-button'
...
```

## _sponsors_fields.html.haml

```
.form-inline.clearfix
    .row
        .nested-fields
            = f.input :sponsorships, :collection => @congress_people

            = link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, class: "form-control btn btn-secondary", style: 'height:20%; display:inline; float:right;'
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple_form this might happen if you accept multiple: true. 
Otherwise, this should be enough:

```
= f.input :sponsorships, :collection => @congress_people
```

furthermore,     `@congress_people` needs to available in your controller method.

Comment: I am using haml it does not use the opening and closing tags.

Comment: I use that exact input in my _sponsors_fields.html.haml and I do not use multiple:true. Since it is an association error I am assuming it has something to do with my models but I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: You should try to find @congress_people and make sure it gets the right input